# Is there a way to specify a default style for a component, without using View?

Tags: react-native

Looking at the React tree in our app, I see a lot of extra `View` tags because (as far as I know) there is no way to set a style on the view that is already containing the `View`. E.g. I have a view called `Thing`, and an onRender:

```
 onRender() {
   ...
   return (
     <View style={theStyle}>
       {contents}
     </View>
   );
 }
```

Looking at the actual generated tree, it would look like:

```
<Tree>  //   <--- how do I set theStyle on this guy so I don't have to have
  <View style={theStyle}>  // <--- this guy
     ...
  </View>
</Tree>
```

Context: We have a pretty complex view hierarchy, and we're trying to do as much as we can to remove extra unnecessary views for speedier rendering.

Comment: Been a while but I just remembered that react-native supports React.Fragment now. Did you solve your problem?